# Is it possible to make Coq accept a class of Fixpoint functions if we provide proofs of argument size reduction?

Tags: coq

I have trees of arbitrary arity, with the following type:

```
Inductive Tree : Set :=
  | Node : list Tree -> Tree.
```

I can easily create a number of Fixpoint functions such as the following one:

```
Fixpoint nodecount (tree: Tree ) : nat :=
    match tree with
     | Node trs => S (sum (map nodecount trs))
    end.
```

but none of the following 'filter' type, even in trivial cases such as this one :

```
Function nodecount' (tree: Tree ) : nat :=
    match tree with
     | Node trs => S (sum (map nodecount' ( filter ( fun x => true) trs)))
    end.
```

Whatever the function behind the filter is, the compiler rejects the function as ill-formed.

Is there a way to provide Coq with a proof that this class of filter functions actually produces well-behaved terms, so that any member of this class of fixpoints is allowed ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use `mapfilter : (A -> option B) -> list A -> list B` instead of `filter` and a separate `map`. You also need to be careful in defining `mapfilter` so that the function argument is not part of the `fix` arguments.

This works because after unfolding `mapfilter` in `nodecount'`, the recursive call to `nodecount'` will be syntactically a subterm of the input `tree`.

```
Definition mapfilter {A B : Type} (f : A -> option B) : list A -> list B :=
  fix mapfilter_f (xs : list A) : list B :=
    match xs with
    | nil => nil
    | x :: xs => match f x with
      | Some y => y :: mapfilter_f xs
      | None => mapfilter_f xs
      end
    end.

Fixpoint nodecount' (p : Tree -> bool) (tree: Tree ) : nat :=
  match tree with
  | Node trs => S (sum (mapfilter (fun x => if p x then Some (nodecount' p x) else None) trs))
  end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can directly write the list recursion into the tree one:

```
Fixpoint nodecount (f : Tree -> bool) (t : Tree) : nat :=
  if (f t) then
  match t with
  | Node l =>
      (fix iter l1 :=
         match l1 with
         | nil => 1
         | (a :: l2)%list => nodecount f a + iter l2
         end) l
  end
  else 0.
```